# session dosnt exist when we send request with ajax or fetch or axios or xmlHttpRequest in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, xmlhttprequest, fetch

when i,m send request ajax with method post. and i,m want check my session in backend.dosnt exist??!!
i,m try any way : with ajax(jquery) or with axios or with fetch or with xmlHttpRequest
notice : i,m add csrf_token in any request too.

```
//this cod worked when i,m not use ajax request.but in ajax request not worked
if($session=session('testSession')){
    return $session;
}
$session=session(['testSession'=>random_int(12,23)]);
return $session;
```

Comment: post your ajax or fetch or axios code

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
use Session;

if (Session::has('testSession')){
   return Session::get('testSession');
}else{
   Session::put('testSession', 123456);
   return Session::get('testSession');
}
```

Comment: this not problem.Does not matter how i,m get sesion.session dos not exist